# Какие существуют примеры реализации микроплатежей в игровых приложениях типа "free2play"?

Tags: разработка-игр

- Каким образом можно,прозрачно, привязать механизм микроплатежей к
  балансу сотового телефона?
- Какие провайдеры предоставляют такой функционал?

На пример, *Qiwi API* не предоставляет раздельных токенов для доступа к кошельку на ввод, и на перевод средств.

Просьба *Steam API* не предлагать.